# Tar Archive Update And Delete Parameters

Tags: updates, delete, tar

I use `-uvf` parameters to tar my home folder, but it accumulates files and I soon run out of disk space.

What combination of parameters **rewrites only changed files and removes deleted**?

Comment: Maybe you have to add the arguments `-r` and `--delete`? Not sure though, just guessing.